# Reverse queryset/list, then slice

Tags: python, django

---

**To whomever marked this as duplicate:** It is not because I have a set of 2 specific goals in a specific order to be made. In the other question it just needs to reverse which is slightly simpler. Thank you for taking your time to READ.

---

I have a Django queryset, which in simpler terms seems to be an extension of lists (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

I need to:

1. Reverse the queryset or list, and then
2. Slice the list

I was doing it in the form of:

`return reversed(querySet)[:20]`

However, now for some reason I am getting the error of:

> "'reversed' object is not subscriptable"

I could easily do:

`return querySet[:20:-1]`

but this causes the list to be sliced first, then ordered backwards.

Thus I am in the process of finding the next best hacky way to achieve this;

but while I find it, I was wondering what your best approach is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Queryset.reverse()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#reverse

`querySet.reverse()[:20]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because, in most cases and it seems to be the case with Django querysets, `reversed` does not produce a list but an iterator:

```
>>> reversed([1,2,3])
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x7f3ba766cc50>
```

And an iterator is not subscriptable. More precisely: it does not have a `__getitem__` method.

Hence, this will not work:

```
>>> reversed([1,2,3])[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list_reverseiterator' object is not subscriptable
```

But this will (create a list from the iterator before accessing an item):

```
>>> list(reversed([1,2,3]))[0]
3
```